# How to find column A values are different but column B values are the same within the same pk

Tags: sql, presto

First of all, I apologize for asking a question through a translator.

I have a presto SQL question.

As shown in the table below, I want to select cases where there are multiple PKs and Item1 is different but Item2 is the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iboTX.png)

When I self-joined, items with three or more items in one PK could not be output.

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired output and attempted query (all in text format so it can be copy-pasted).

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table if exists temp_test;
create temp table temp_test (pk smallint,item1 varchar(30),item2 varchar(30));
insert into temp_test values 
    (1,'red shirts','green shirts'),
    (1,'blue shirts','green shirts'),
    (2,'yellow cap','black cap'),
    (3,'green car','blue car'),
    (4,'purple handkerchief','red handkerchief'),
    (5,'red socks','white socks'),
    (5,'yellow socks','white socks'),
    (5,'green socks','white socks'),
    (6,'silver plate','platin plate'),
    (6,'silver plate','platin plate')
;
with 
    stacks as (
        select 
            pk,
            count(distinct item1) item1,
            count(distinct item2) item2
        from 
            temp_test 
        group by 1
    )
select
    a.pk,
    a.item2
from
    temp_test a
    inner join stacks on (
        a.pk = stacks.pk
        and stacks.item1 != stacks.item2
    )
group by 1,2
```

Comment: But Item1 in the same PK must be different. What should I do to put such a condition?

Comment: your example data didn't include this case. i updated the sql